# How to fix error agrep: pattern too long (has > 32 chars) it doesn't show error if there is no full stop in the string?

Tags: bash, agrep

agrep gives the error `agrep: pattern too long (has > 32 chars)` when there is a full stop(.) in the pattern string but not otherwise.

I want to compare(approximately) two strings, so I'm using agrep for that but its giving an error `agrep: pattern too long (has > 32 chars)` . But I found out that it doesn't give the error if there is no full stop in the pattern string(why?)

```
`echo "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog." | agrep -c -4 "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog."`
```

expected output is 1 instead it gives an error:
`agrep: pattern too long (has > 32 chars)`

it works if I remove the full stop:

```
$ echo "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog." | agrep -c -4 "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog"  
1
```

Comment: From `man agrep`: *The limit of record length can be changed by modifying the parameter Max_record in agrep.h.*

Comment: @Cyrus it works if there is no full stop in the pattern string, no matter how large the string is.

Comment: Maybe you want to take a look at `tre-agrep`.

Comment: @Cyrus can you tell me how I can use tre-agrep on a string instead of a whole file. I tried `echo "the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog." | tre-agrep -4 "the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog` but it just echos the string

Comment: You mean that? `echo "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog." | tre-agrep -c -4 "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog."`

Comment: @Cyrus yes, the full stop is working now but `tre-agrep` doesn't pipe echo

Comment: It's unclear what output you want.

Comment: @Cyrus I want to compare two strings, approximately, the command should return True(1) if they match(approx) or False(0) if they don't. Normally `agrep` or `tre-agrep` compares the pattern with lines in a file but I want to compare with a string. ideally it should be something like `command -c -4 "string_to_compare"  "pattern_string"` output 1 or 0 accordingly

Answer (score 2):

Approximate string matching / fuzzy string searching with two strings.

With `agrep` and `bash`:

```
if agrep -1 "abc" <<< "xbc" >/dev/null; then echo "match"; else echo "no match"; fi
```

or with `tre-agrep` and `bash`:

```
if tre-agrep -q -1 "abc" <<< "xbc"; then echo "match"; else echo "no match"; fi
```

Output in both cases:

```
match
```

Comment: why does it show match for `if tre-agrep -q -1 "abc" <<< "xbcdefadf"; then echo "match"; else echo "no match"; fi`? 
the -1 maximum number of errors permitted is not applying

Comment: `abc` is with one error a substring of `xbcdefadf`. Match starts at position 0 and ends after 3 characters. See: `tre-agrep -1 --show-position "abc" <<< "xbcdefadf"`

Comment: Is there a way I could compare the two strings such that it looks for maximum number of errors in the whole string. i don't want to search for the string in the file but check if the  string(line) matches approximately to the operand string(like if its just a typo or completely different line)
i.e "the" should not match "the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog" the whole sentence should be approximately same

Comment: I recommend to start a new question, because this would go beyond the scope.

Comment: agrep -x: 'the pattern must match the whole line' does what I was looking for, but still it shows error pattern is too long(has > 32 chars). Can you tell me how to change the limit of pattern length using agrep.h? I found the /usr/bin/agrep file but don't know what to change.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `agrep` is treating `.` as a meta character. To avoid that you must pass the option `-k`:

```
echo "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog." | agrep -c -4 -k "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog."
```

The man page on agrep says:

> -k     No  symbol  in  the pattern is treated as a meta character.

Answer (score 0):

The limit of 32 characters has to do with the register width it is optimized for: 32 bit. See `#define WORD 32` in agrep.h.

Switch to 64 bit seems to be more work than changing `unsigned` to `unsigned long` and doubling constants in agrep.h.