# Is there any command to do fuzzy matching in Linux based on multiple columns

Tags: linux, join, awk, levenshtein-distance

I have two csv file. 
File 1

```
D,FNAME,MNAME,LNAME,GENDER,DOB,snapshot
2,66M,J,Rock,F,1995,201211.0
3,David,HM,Lee,M,,201211.0
6,66M,,Rock,F,,201211.0
0,David,H M,Lee,,1990,201211.0
3,Marc,H,Robert,M,2000,201211.0
6,Marc,M,Robert,M,,201211.0
6,Marc,MS,Robert,M,2000,201211.0
3,David,M,Lee,,1990,201211.0
5,Paul,ABC,Row,F,2008,201211.0
3,Paul,ACB,Row,,,201211.0
4,David,,Lee,,1990,201211.0
4,66,J,Rock,,1995,201211.0
```

File 2

```
PID,FNAME,MNAME,LNAME,GENDER,DOB
S2,66M,J,Rock,F,1995
S3,David,HM,Lee,M,1990
S0,Marc,HM,Robert,M,2000
S1,Marc,MS,Robert,M,2000
S6,Paul,,Row,M,2008
S7,Sam,O,Baby,F,2018
```

What I want to do is to use the crosswalk file, File 2, to back out those observations' PID in File 1 based on Columns FNAME,MNAME,LNAME,GENDER, and DOB. Because the corresponding information in observations of File 1 is not complete, I'm thinking of using fuzzy matching to back out their PID as many as possible (of course the level accuracy should be taken into account). For example, the observations with FNAME "Paul" and LNAME "Row" in File 1 should be assigned the same PID because there is only one similar observation in File 2. But for the observations with FNAME "Marc" and LNAME "Robert", `Marc,MS,Robert,M,2000,201211.0` should be assigned PID "S1", `Marc,H,Robert,M,2000,201211.0` PID "S0" and `Marc,M,Robert,M,,201211.0` either "S0" or "S1".

Since I want to compensate File 1's PID as many as possible while keeping high accuracy, I consider three steps. First, use command to make sure that  if and only if those information in FNAME,MNAME,LNAME,GENDER, and DOB are all completely matched, observations in File 1 can be assigned a PID. The output should be

```
D,FNAME,MNAME,LNAME,GENDER,DOB,snapshot,PID
2,66M,J,Rock,F,1995,201211.0,S2
3,David,HM,Lee,M,,201211.0,
6,66M,,Rock,F,,201211.0,
0,David,H M,Lee,,1990,201211.0,
3,Marc,H,Robert,M,2000,201211.0,
6,Marc,M,Robert,M,,201211.0,
6,Marc,MS,Robert,M,2000,201211.0,
3,David,M,Lee,,1990,201211.0,
5,Paul,ABC,Row,F,2008,201211.0,
3,Paul,ACB,Row,,,201211.0,
4,David,,Lee,,1990,201211.0,
4,66,J,Rock,,1995,201211.0,
```

Next, write another command to guarantee that while DOB information are completely same, use fuzzy matching for FNAME,MNAME,LNAME,GENDER to back out File 1's observations' PID, which is not identified in the first step. So the output through these two steps is supposed to be

```
D,FNAME,MNAME,LNAME,GENDER,DOB,snapshot,PID
2,66M,J,Rock,F,1995,201211.0,S2
3,David,HM,Lee,M,,201211.0,
6,66M,,Rock,F,,201211.0,
0,David,H M,Lee,,1990,201211.0,S3
3,Marc,H,Robert,M,2000,201211.0,S0
6,Marc,M,Robert,M,,201211.0,
6,Marc,MS,Robert,M,2000,201211.0,S1
3,David,M,Lee,,1990,201211.0,S3
5,Paul,ABC,Row,F,2008,201211.0,S6
3,Paul,ACB,Row,,,201211.0,
4,David,,Lee,,1990,201211.0,S3
4,66,J,Rock,,1995,201211.0,S2
```

In the final step, use a new command to do fuzzy matching for all related columns, namely FNAME,MNAME,LNAME,GENDER, and DOB to compensate the remained observations' PID. So the final output is expected to be

```
D,FNAME,MNAME,LNAME,GENDER,DOB,snapshot,PID
2,66M,J,Rock,F,1995,201211.0,S2
3,David,HM,Lee,M,,201211.0,S3
6,66M,,Rock,F,,201211.0,S2
0,David,H M,Lee,,1990,201211.0,S3
3,Marc,H,Robert,M,2000,201211.0,S0
6,Marc,M,Robert,M,,201211.0,S1
6,Marc,MS,Robert,M,2000,201211.0,S1
3,David,M,Lee,,1990,201211.0,S3
5,Paul,ABC,Row,F,2008,201211.0,S6
3,Paul,ACB,Row,,,201211.0,S6
4,David,,Lee,,1990,201211.0,S3
4,66,J,Rock,,1995,201211.0,S2
```

I need to keep the order of File 1's observations so it must be kind of leftouter join. Because my original data size is about 100Gb, I want to use Linux to deal with my issue. 
But I have no idea how to complete the last two steps through `awk` or any other command in Linux. Is there anyone who can give me a favor? Thank you.

Comment: This dup target is off-site: https://askubuntu.com/questions/753608/is-there-any-program-for-fuzzy-string-matching-which-provides-a-match-score so I can't add it.

Comment: Take a look at `agrep` or `tre-agrep`. [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57534653/3776858).

Comment: If you just read the title, there closing was justified, but if you read the whole question (I know, TL;DR, almost skipped it myself) I don't think that's enough.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a shot at it with GNU awk (using `PROCINFO["sorted_in"]` to pick the most suitable candidate). It hashes the `file2`'s field values per field and attaches the `PID` to the value, like `field[2]["66M"]="S2"` and for each record in `file1` counts the amounts of `PID` matches and prints the one with the biggest count:

```
BEGIN {
    FS=OFS=","
    PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@val_num_desc"
}
NR==FNR {                                                      # file2
    for(i=1;i<=6;i++)                                          # fields 1-6
        if($i!="") {
        field[i][$i]=field[i][$i] (field[i][$i]==""?"":OFS) $1 # attach PID to value
    }
    next
}
{                                                               # file1
        for(i=1;i<=6;i++) {                                     # fields 1-6
            if($i in field[i]) {                                # if value matches
                split(field[i][$i],t,FS)                        # get PIDs
                for(j in t) {                                   # and
                    matches[t[j]]++                             # increase PID counts
                }
            } else {                                            # if no value match
                for(j in field[i])                              # for all field values
                    if($i~j || j~$i)                            # "go fuzzy" :D
                        matches[field[i][j]]+=0.5               # fuzzy is half a match
            }
        }
        for(i in matches) {                                     # the best match first
            print $0,i
            delete matches
            break                                               # we only want the best match
        }
}
```

Output:

```
D,FNAME,MNAME,LNAME,GENDER,DOB,snapshot,PID
2,66M,J,Rock,F,1995,201211.0,S2
3,David,HM,Lee,M,,201211.0,S3
6,66M,,Rock,F,,201211.0,S2
0,David,H M,Lee,,1990,201211.0,S3
3,Marc,H,Robert,M,2000,201211.0,S0
6,Marc,M,Robert,M,,201211.0,S1
6,Marc,MS,Robert,M,2000,201211.0,S1
3,David,M,Lee,,1990,201211.0,S3
5,Paul,ABC,Row,F,2008,201211.0,S6
3,Paul,ACB,Row,,,201211.0,S6
4,David,,Lee,,1990,201211.0,S3
4,66,J,Rock,,1995,201211.0,S2
```

The "fuzzy match" here is naivistic `if($i~j || j~$i)` but feel free to replace it with any approximate matching algorithm, for example there are a few implementations of the Levenshtein distance algorithms floating in the internets. Rosetta seems to have one.

You didn't mention how big `file2` is but if it's way beyond your memory capasity, you may want to consider spliting the files somehow.

**Update**: A version that maps `file1` fields to `file2` fields (as mentioned in comments):

```
BEGIN {
    FS=OFS=","
    PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@val_num_desc"
    map[1]=1                                                   # map file1 fields to file2 fields
    map[2]=3
    map[3]=4
    map[4]=2
    map[5]=5
    map[7]=6
}
NR==FNR {                                                      # file2
    for(i=1;i<=6;i++)                                          # fields 1-6
        if($i!="") {
        field[i][$i]=field[i][$i] (field[i][$i]==""?"":OFS) $1 # attach PID to value
    }
    next
}
{                                                              # file1
    for(i in map) {
        if($i in field[map[i]]) {                              # if value matches
            split(field[map[i]][$i],t,FS)                      # get PIDs
            for(j in t) {                                      # and
                matches[t[j]]++                                # increase PID counts
            }
        } else {                                               # if no value match
            for(j in field[map[i]])                            # for all field values
                if($i~j || j~$i)                               # "go fuzzy" :D
                    matches[field[map[i]][j]]+=0.5             # fuzzy is half a match
        }
    }
    for(i in matches) {                                        # the best match first
        print $0,i
        delete matches
        break                                                  # we only want the best match
    }
}
```

Comment: I really appreciate for your help. File 2 is around 10 Gb. I am new with `awk` so would you mind giving me some explanation on the meaning of the content in the parenthesis of `field[i][$i]=field[i][$i] (field[i][$i]==""?"":OFS) $1`?  And what does `t` and `FS` indicate in `split(field[i][$i],t,FS)`? Plus in the final loop `for(i in matches) ...` how can you make sure the best match will be selected? Cuz I did not find how the best match is sorted out. And I have another subissue. Suppose the order of fields in File 1 like `D, MNAME, LNAME, FNAME, GENDER, snapshot, DOB`.Then how shall I do?

Comment: Hi, I typed your code, `awk '[yourcode]' file2 file1` in the terminal but it did not work. The terminal warned that there exists syntax error in the format of squared bracket in `field[i][$i]=field[i][$i] (field[i][$i]==""?"":OFS) $1` plus all the brackets in the loop for file1.

Comment: You are using GNU awk, right? The script has multidimensional arrays and changed `for` travese ordering, both GNU awk features.

Comment: When I enter `awk --help`, it showed the message `Usage: awk [POSIX or GNU style options] -f progfile [--] file ... Usage: awk [POSIX or GNU style options] [--] 'program' file ...
POSIX options: GNU long options: .....`.

Comment: How about `awk --version`?

Comment: It is GNU Awk 3.1.7

Comment: Sorry, can't test on such an old version. Version 5 is out, I'm still on version 4.*. You might want to upgrade you GNU awk.

Comment: For the first comment. There is not enough room to teach you syntax here, add `print variable`s here and there and see how it works. For the best match, we count points for matches and by changing the `for` traverse order to `"@val_num_desc"` (order is to get the biggest array value first), that's GNU awk stuff. About the field orders, now we use `for(1...6)` since the fields are in the same order in the files. If the orders differ, you need to compare one by one or make a mapping. `map[1]=2; i=1; field[map[i]]` is equal to `field[2]`. `(field[i][$i]==""?"":OFS)` is `if(..)=="" then "" else ,`

Comment: Updated with a mapping version.

Comment: I am aware that you are actually using the information of the first field in File 1 to do matching. That filed is not related to those matching variables. Why we need to use it?

Comment: Probably didn't pay attention. You can remove it from the `for` loops and mapping.

Comment: Because the original files are two large, I split them into small files. File 1 size is 18 Gb now while File 2 is 300Mb. I applied for 10 cores and 20Gb RAM per core. Then I applied your method but there is zero output after I ran over 4 hrs. Could you give me some advice? Thank you.

Comment: Awk runs single core. If you want to speed things up for testing or such, comment out that `else { ... }` block aka. _the fuzzy part_, that's where the time is spent. Really can't help from over here but if it returns nothing, maybe it runs out of memory or somrething. Comment that `else` block out, it runs faster, follow the process size with top and see if that's the reason.

Comment: Sorry to bother your again. I am still working on this issue. To reduce the required memory, I am thinking of impose a condition on the fuzzy matching, which is LNAME and Gender must be completely matched. My question is how to revise your code to achieve it. Thank you.