# Old Version problem: Errors in fuzzy matching based on multiple columns using AWK

Tags: linux, awk

I tried to use the code provided in the answer,[Is there any command to do fuzzy matching in Linux based on multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58254198/is-there-any-command-to-do-fuzzy-matching-in-linux-based-on-multiple-columns) , to do fuzzy matching. However, when I typed

```
awk 'codesinanswer' test2.csv test1.csv
```

in the terminal. I received the following warning messages.

```
awk: cmd. line:7:         field[i][$i]=field[i][$i] (field[i][$i]==""?"":OFS) $1 # attach PID to value
awk: cmd. line:7:                 ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:7:         field[i][$i]=field[i][$i] (field[i][$i]==""?"":OFS) $1 # attach PID to value
awk: cmd. line:7:                              ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:7:         field[i][$i]=field[i][$i] (field[i][$i]==""?"":OFS) $1 # attach PID to value
awk: cmd. line:7:                                            ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:7:         field[i][$i]=field[i][$i] (field[i][$i]==""?"":OFS) $1 # attach PID to value
awk: cmd. line:7:                                                             ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:12:         for(i=1;i<=6;i++) {                                     # fields 1-6
awk: cmd. line:12:                           ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:13:             if($i in field[i]) {                                # if value matches
awk: cmd. line:13:                                ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:15:                 split(field[i][$i],t,FS)                        # get PIDs
awk: cmd. line:15:                                                                 ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:15:                 for(j in t) {                                   # and
awk: cmd. line:15:                             ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:20:                 for(j in field[i])                              # for all field values
awk: cmd. line:20:                                                                 ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:21:                     if($i~j || j~$i)                            # "go fuzzy" :D
awk: cmd. line:21:                                                                 ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:24:         for(i in matches) {                                     # the best match first
awk: cmd. line:24:                           ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:25:             print $0,i;
awk: cmd. line:25:                       ^ syntax erro
```

I'm using GNU Awk 3.1.7.

How shall I deal with it? Thank you.

Comment: Install GNU awk, multimensional arrays is a GNU extension, other awks (afaik) don't have it

Comment: I'm no version guru but I'd start by upgrading the version.

Comment: That [array of array](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Arrays-of-Arrays.html) syntax was added in gnu awk 4.0. Follow @JamesBrown 's advice if you want to use it.

Comment: @JamesBrown I installed the version GNUGawk5.0.1. Now it works. If you are convenient, would you mind also answering my previous subquestion in the above link? It's about the change of corresponding variables' order and details in your code. Thank you.

Comment: 3.1.7 was released in July **2009**, btw. Literally a decade ago...

Comment: @Shawn It's a school computer. So usually we don't know what the version is unless we suffered problems like above. It's expected that the system is supposed to be updated normally.

Comment: We're on gawk 5.0.1 now. 3.1.7 is missing a few bug fixes and a TON of extremely useful functionality including arrays of arrays as you're trying to use.

Answer (score 0):

Just to close this: Use a modern version of GNU awk. See the comments to the OP.